# Data value become nil after getting out of the closure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to create a DataAccess layer for handling data access with firebase. Inside the closure, I can see data variable get 3 items, but once it gets out of the closure and go to return statement, it becomes nil!

```
static let ref = Database.database()

static func GetGames(completion : @escaping ([String]) ->()){
    ref.reference(withPath: "games").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String] else { return }
        completion(data)
    })
    { (error) in
        print("failed to fitch data",error)

    }
}
```

and her is my call

```
DataAccess.GetGames { (items) in
    self.games = items
}
```

Comment: The closure executes asynchronously after the network operation completes, which is after the `GetGames` function returns, so data is `nil` *before* the closure executes and that is what your function returns.  You cannot `return` data retrieved asynchronously.  You need to pass a closure to `GetGames` (which should be `getGames` by convention) and invoke the passed closure from the `observe` closure.

Comment: @Paulw11 one second, I am testing that

Comment: @Paulw11 samething, it becomes nil https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvxwkcrmfhk2ixr/Screenshot%202017-09-07%2015.33.23.png?dl=0

Comment: and here's my call  DataAccess.GetGames { (items) in
            self.games = items
        }

Comment: @Paulw11 i updated the code

Comment: It's still asynchronous. Move your print. `DataAccess.GetGames({ (items) in self.games = items; print(self.games) })`, not `DataAccess.GetGames({ (items) in self.games = items }) print(self.games)`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, I now understand the trick